# How to handle Dapper SQL connection with multiple async functions

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, connection-pooling, dapper, using

I have a question about Dapper. My `SqlRepository` contains a lot of asynchronous functions to execute and query various stored procedures. Sample code looks like this and imagine many functions like this, called every few seconds:

```
Public Async Function GetTemperatureMeasurements() As Task(Of List(Of TemperatureMeasurements))
        Try
            Using conn = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.SqlConn)
Return (Await conn.QueryAsync(Of TemperatureMeasurements)("dbo.GetTemperatureMeasurement", commandType:=CommandType.StoredProcedure)).ToList()
            End Using
        Catch ex As SqlException
            _ea.PublishEvent(New OnSqlError() With {.Msg = ex.Message})
            Return Nothing
        End Try
Exit function
```

My question is whether it is correct to use `using ... end using` in each function to open and close the connection with Dapper and what happens when an execution occurs? Will Dapper close the connection and manage the connection pool correctly?

I had an overflow exception regarding this because of the connection pool (The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached).

Thank you!

Comment: But this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling?view=netframework-4.8 says the same pool is used when sqlconnections have same connection string, so my code should be correct.

Comment: The first comment is a bit misleading and may be indicative of a misunderstanding. ADO.NET connection objects exist at a high level. Yes, you should create, use, dispose and discard them as needed. As you suggest, due to connection pooling, multiple ADO.NET connection objects with the same connection string will actually use the same underlying database connection. That underlying connection stays open for some time after it's used in case it is needed again so creating the multiple high-level ADO.NET connection objects is not expensive.

Comment: In short, you use as many connection objects as you need and ADO.NET will use just one under the hood.